# Can we and how safe is to "signed" to "unsigned" trick to save one comparison in this case?

Tags: c++, c, comparison, unsigned-integer

For example

```
bool CheckWithinBoundary(int x, int b) {
  return (x>=0) && (x <= b);
}
bool CheckWithinBoundary2(int x, int b) { 
  return static_cast<uint32>(x) <= static_cast<uint32>(b);
}
```

CheckWithinBoundary2 can save one comparison.

My question is:

1. Can today's compiler optimize code using this? Or how can I make the
   compiler do this kind of optimization?
2. Is there any danger to use this trick?

Comment: If you're asking for array boundaries, these are already of type `size_t`, which usually expands to `unsigned long`, and not `int` typically.

Comment: If by compiler optimization you are referring to the notion that comparing two `int`s is slower than comparing two `uint32`s, what evidence do you have that that is the case? And, to answer your second question, yes, you cannot safely cast freely between signed data types and their unsigned counterparts.

Comment: What happens if INT_MAX > INT32_MAX ?

Comment: @Chris: The OP is asking, whether a compiler can optimize the first implementation into something like the second implementation. I'd guess, this is not the case.

Comment: well if `x = -2147483647` and `b = 2147483649` `CheckWithinBoundary2()` will return true even though `x` is negative.

Comment: @IInspectable the two implementations look non-equivalent to me, so I don't believe the compiler would optimize something to be incorrect.

Comment: @ChrisSprague, sure you can always safely cast from signed types to unsigned types. This is well defined. The other direction is problematic.

Comment: @JensGustedt Sure, but the result isn't always what you want it to be.

Comment: @this how do you know what *I* want it to be :) But more seriously, as long as the target unsigned type is wide enough, that is exactly what you want it to be.

Comment: You do not address any signed/unsigned compare problem (your function arguments ('int') just ignore it)

Comment: @JensGustedt really? I thought something like `int x = -1` casted to an `unsigned int` would give you something like `INT_MAX + 1` (or maybe `UINT_MAX-1` because of 2's complement, but the point is, it thought it wouldn't be `-1`)

Comment: @JensGustedt You always want the abstract values to return the same result as the casted C values. Unsigned int might not be width enough for int. It is possible that INT_MAX  == UINT_MAX.

Comment: @ChrisSprague, converting to an unsigned type always does computation modulo the corresponding power of 2. So `-1U` is nothing else than `UINT_MAX`, always, on all architectures. And the result has nothing to do with the sign representation of the signed type, these things use the value and not the representation.

Comment: 1. I know that Visual Studio has been using this optimization technique for a while. Can't say anything about other compilers.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to 2 is, yes, there is, these two are not the same. It seems that you are silently assuming that `b >= 0`, too. Consider e.g `x == 1` and `b == -1`, this would give `false` for the first case and `true` for the second.

(I switch to C notation, this is easier to me, and since you also seem to be interested in it)

So we have that in fact

```
static_assert(INT_MAX < UINT_MAX);

bool CheckWithinBoundary(int x, int b) {
  return (b >=0) && (x>=0) && (x <= b);
}
bool CheckWithinBoundary2(unsigned x, unsigned b) { 
  return (b >=0) && (x <= b);
}
```

if it compiles, are equivalent on all architectures where `INT_MAX < UINT_MAX`, and then the implicit conversion `int --> unsigned` does the right thing.

But be careful, you note that I use `unsigned` and not `uint32_t`, because you have to be sure to use an unsigned type with the same width. I don't know if there are architectures with 64 bit `int`, but there your method would fail.

Comment: Thanks! However, if I write code with your implementation 1 (i.e. testing (x>=0) && (b >=0) && (x <= b) ), the compiler I'm using will simply do three comparisons instead of one comparison, is there anyway to hint compiler to do the optimization?

Comment: @NanHua, could you please reformulate your question, I don't understand.

Comment: @NanHua, I don't know why you would want to do this, the unsigned type for `int` *is* `unsigned`. But my C++ is too rusty for these kind of constructs.

Comment: wouldn't `CheckWithinBoundary2(-2, -1)` give the wrong results? `CheckWithinBoundary()` returns `false`, but `CheckWithinBoundary2()` returns `true`

Comment: @WorldSEnder, yeah right, actually both suppose that `b >= 0`.