# How to make the C++ compiler to use the unsigned to signed trick for optimization of comparison

Tags: c++, comparison, unsigned-integer

So from what I know the following two functions' behavior should be exactly the same.
However, if I implement using the first one, the compiler seems can't realize it's equivalent to the second. Is there anyway to hint the compiler to use the second ?

In another words, I hate to do the static_cast things... Anyway to avoid it?

```
// In my real use case, range will never be negative....
// All I want is to return (diff > range || diff < 0) assuming range >=0
bool IsOutofRange1(int diff, int range) {
  if ((range >= 0) && (diff > range || diff < 0)) return true;
  if (range < 0 && diff > range && diff < 0) return true;
  return false;
}

bool IsOutofRange2(int diff, int range) {
  if (static_cast<unsigned>(diff) > static_cast<unsigned>(range)) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you hate `static_cast`?

Comment: @GWW Well you should hate all casts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347420/can-we-and-how-safe-is-to-signed-to-unsigned-trick-to-save-one-comparison-in

Comment: If in the "...real use case, range will never be negative...." and all you "... want is to return (diff > range || diff < 0) assuming range >=0 ...", why don't  you `return (diff > range || diff < 0)` in the first place?

Comment: @zenith: I hope you are being facetious

Comment: Because 'range' usually implies 2 values - an upper limit and a lower limit,  can you provide your definition of range?

Comment: What about `return (((range >= 0) + (diff > range) + (diff < 0)) >= 2);` ?

Comment: You asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347420/can-we-and-how-safe-is-to-signed-to-unsigned-trick-to-save-one-comparison-in) some hours ago. And you got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your range in never negative, why do you use a signed type for it (yeah, I know you hate casting) ? How about overloading:

```
bool IsOutofRange(int diff, int range)
{
    ....
}

bool IsOutofRange(int diff, unsigned range)
{
    if (static_cast<unsigned>(diff) > range) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Of course to force compiler to use the second version you would (oh my God...):

```
IsOutofRange(diff,static_cast<unsigned>(range));
```

I hope that helps, and I am deeply sorry about the static_cast'ing.